# How to implement animation on removing element from recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, gridlayoutmanager

I was trying to implement this [Animation](https://www.screencast.com/t/ugXQM9cscU4) when an item is removed from the  `Recycler View` which uses a `GridLayoutManager`. I used the below code for the item click but the animation that comes out is different from the one expected. How can this be correctly implemented?

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rv);
                    }

                    removeItem(position);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Post some code to get help. Unable to understand the exact problem here.

Comment: Added in some more details @shubhamvashisht

Answer (score 0):

Implement Animation on ItemView something like following

Updated Answer

As per your requirement as you mentioned in link.
You need to do two thing:

1. Perform RotationY animation
2. Update RecyclerView'Adapter's data.

Coming to first part.

Set `CameraDistance` as per requirement to change the perspective.

Set Pivot point if required.

Use ObjectAnimator or ValueAnimator.

Sample code is following:

```
        view.setPivotX();
        view.setPivotY();

        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,"rotationY",0,180);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(10000);
```

Coming to second part.

Set AnitionListener. And perform your adapter updation code inside `OnEndAnimation()` Callback

Something like following:

```
objectAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            .......
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                // remove an element of  recyclerview's adapter data list
                // notify adapter about data removal like adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

            }
            ......
```

**Note: No need to set Translation Animation.This simulation will come automatically when you update data removal in adapter**

For more reference
 [Official Document is here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator)

Happy Coding.

Comment: In translate animation, if we've to move one recycler view(grid) item to another one's position as given in the animation in question, what parameters should be given?